# How can I use rsync via ssh in cron?

Tags: ssh, cron, rsync

I have a private virtual server to which I'm trying backup some directories from local my `/home` directory.

I've prepared this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/rsync -rvvv /home/arkadiusz/scripts root@XXX.XXX.26.106:/home/backup/

/usr/bin/notify-send "Backup complete" "~/scripts -> vps" -i cryptkeeper
```

In user's crontab I've added entry:

```
*/1 * * * * /home/arkadiusz/scripts/vps.sh > /home/arkadiusz/cron-vps.log 2> /home/arkadiusz/cron-vps.error.log
```

After executing the shell script, my `scripts` directory doesn't appear in `/home/backup/` on the remote server. In `cron-vps.log` file I see only this:

```
opening connection using: ssh -l root XXX.XXX.26.106 rsync --server -vvvre.iLsfx . /home/backup/  (9 args)
[sender] _exit_cleanup(code=12, file=io.c, line=226): about to call exit(255)
```

In `cron-vps.error.log` file turns out that this is an authorization problem:

```
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.1]
```

---

I've checked additionally `sshd` status on my remote server:

```
root@vpsXXXXXX:/home/backup# service sshd status
● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2017-04-12 01:04:09 CEST; 12h ago
 Main PID: 281 (sshd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service
           └─281 /usr/sbin/sshd -D

...

Apr 12 13:41:01 vpsXXXXXX.ovh.net sshd[5019]: Failed password for root from XXX.XXX.232.122 port 21782 ssh2
Apr 12 13:41:01 vpsXXXXXX.ovh.net sshd[5019]: Failed password for root from XXX.XXX.232.122 port 21782 ssh2
Apr 12 13:41:01 vpsXXXXXX.ovh.net sshd[5019]: Connection closed by XXX.XXX.232.122 port 21782 [preauth]
```

Based on these logs, it seems to be a problem with authorization, but my SSH connection works when I try to log in to my remote sever with this command:

```
ssh root@XXX.XXX.26.106
```

Also, the `rsync` command works in terminal without any passwords:

```
/usr/bin/rsync -rvvv /home/arkadiusz/scripts root@XXX.XXX.26.106:/home/backup/
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try with `sudo` on cron file

Comment: @Ravi, unfortunatelly it doesn't work. Logs:


cron-vps.log: `opening connection using: ssh -l root 5.196.26.106 rsync --server -vvvre.iLsfx . /home/backup/  (9 args)`
`[sender] _exit_cleanup(code=12, file=io.c, line=226): about to call exit(255)`
cron-vps.error.log:
`grep: /proc//environ: No such file or directory`
`Host key verification failed.`
`rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]`
`rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.1]`

Comment: First try to run script manually and let me know

Comment: Manually works perfectly, both script and one-line command in terminal.

Comment: Have you try this way `rsync -v -v -e '/usr/bin/ssh -p YY' ./testfile me@XXXXX:/home` ?

Comment: How are you authenticating as root to the the remote server (password? public key with passphrase? public key with empty passphrase?) and how exactly did you set it up?

Comment: @steeldriver I'm authenticating as root to the remote server by public key with passphrase. On my server I've uploaded public key by `ssh-copy-id` command and after this operation I can log in to my server manually from terminal and use rsync manually too. I didn't set anything else.

Comment: So presumably you are not typing your passphrase every time when you run the command manually because it is being cached by an *agent* (e.g. `ssh-agent`) within your desktop session - likely the script doesn't have access to that cached credential when run via cron. I'd suggest setting up a separate keypair with empty passphrase for automated rsync.

Comment: @Ravi I've tried it doesn't work :<

@steeldriver I've created separated key with empty passphrase. On remote server in `.ssh/authorized_keys` file I left one entry consistent with new key, and still `rsync` works only manually, but not in cron. I see different error in my log cron-vps.error.log file:
`ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/bin/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory`
`Permission denied, please try again.`
`ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/bin/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory`
`Permission denied (publickey,password).`

Is cron associated with some context for ssh?

Comment: Here you have three option , 1) remove passphrase on key 2)  manually add passphrase on script using `expect` 3) use ssh-agent, better option you can choose.

Comment: Remember that these always need to be "push" commands.  The sudo only applies to the system where the script is run from.  So the backup scripts are run on the remote devices and push their data to the "server"

Comment: Using root is problematic for cron.  Usually it runs in the user text -
 the user that submits the job.  So if you are running cron in pi and expecting it to login as root on the far sermachine you will need to establish root creds in order to get it to run.  It is best to use hte same login name on both ends.  Also, remember that these always need to be "push" commands.  The sudo only applies to the system where the script is run from, so it can access the source files.  Make sure things work at the command line before trying to cron them.  And ALWAYS use fully-qualified pathnames.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In cron-vps.error.log file turns out that this is an authorization problem:

The authentication and authorization is a different problem. This is authentication, which fails (in this case the password, as visible from the logs).

Most probably you have set up your private key to be encrypted, but you do not notice it it normal sessions, because you have got it stored in the `ssh-agent`. It works fine in your session, but that won't work in the session that is initiated from your `crontab`.

Comment: What can I do to get it working? If I understand correctly it's a problem with my private key.  Is it depends on access to file by permissions and cron has no access to this?

Comment: Verify if your key has a passphrase/is encrypted. If so, either remote the passphrase or generate separate key in different location used for your rsync and make sure you can connect with it ( use switches `-oIdentityFile=/path/to/key -oIdentitiesOnly=yes`).

Comment: Thanks @Jakuje and @Ravi I've used key without passphrase and works great under cron:

`/usr/bin/rsync -rvvv -e "ssh -i $HOME/.ssh/backup-key" /home/arkadiusz/scripts root@XXX.XXX.26.106:/home/backup/`